# Prove that there is an even number of faces whose vertices get all three labels in a graph that is triangular

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Consider a planar drawing of a graph all whose faces, including the
outer one, are triangular (i.e., have 3 vertices). To each vertex, we arbitrarily assign one of the labels 1,2,3. Prove that there is an even number of faces whose vertices get all three labels.

I'm trying to prove the above and I got very close with my intuition but I'm not yet there. This is what I did:

[image: my sol]

I assigned odd degree with having all the three vertices. The red one is the only one that has all of them and the outer one i guess. We know that it can't only be the red one because by handshake lemma we know that the number of vertices with an odd degree is even but is this a good proof? And can I assign stuff like I did?

Comment: I suggest you look at this:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_lemma  .  Note that in your figure the coloring of the vertices along the edges of the large triangle satisfies an extra condition.

Comment: dtldarek already mentioned this in his answer, but just to make sure it is noticed: In your example, the outer face has 13 vertices, not 3. Each of those outside vertices counts as a vertex for it, whether you draw the connecting edges in the same straight line or not.

Comment: You have flagged to have this question deleted. We don't delete questions, and especially those with upvoted answers, barring extreme circumstances. You also suggested that you posted this question without permission from the question designer --- this is bad. To resolve an IP issue, it is necessary for the claimant to contact SE directly, perhaps by using the `Contact Us` link at the bottom of a page.

Comment: The graph that you draw is not plane triangulation. Because the infinite face (unbounded region) is not triangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track.

First, in your example the outer face is not triangular. 
Second, you cannot just assign odd degrees, what you should do, is to define a graph in such a way that the right vertices will have odd degrees.

So let's define a (multi)graph $G'$ that will have faces of $G$ as vertices, and there will be an edge between two vertices $f_1$ and $f_2$ of $G'$ (i.e., faces of $G$) when:

1. Faces $f_1$ and $f_2$ share an edge in $G$.
2. Labels on the endpoints of the shared edge in $G$ are different.

Technically we should make $G'$ a multigraph, because two faces can share more than one edge. With such a definition, indeed the vertices of $G'$ (which are faces of $G$) have an odd degree if and only if all three labels different (degree zero if there is only one unique labels and degree two if there are two unique labels).

Finally, if you are uncomfortable using faces of $G$ as vertices of $G'$, you can map them to numbers, that is, if $G$ has $F \in \mathbb{N}$ faces, then we will number them arbitrarily as $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_{F}$ and then construct graph $G'$ on the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, F\}$. In this way there is a one-to-one correspondence between the vertices of $G'$ and faces of $G$ and so the whole reasoning works just as well. See also the definition of a [dual graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) (e.g., $G'$ is a subgraph of the dual of $G$).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji I would like to, but I don't have enough time right now, sorry. Perhaps the other answers will suit you better. If you have some particular question, you can ask and I may reply if I happen to have a free minute later today or tomorrow.

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji - follow his link for the dual graph. Note in particular that first diagram, which gives a nice example. dtldarek's graph $G'$ is obtained from the dual graph simply by deleting every edge that crosses an edge of the original graph whose endpoints have the same label.